# SQL - multiple fields from subquery feeding into main query

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 2 discrete queries, both of which return results exactly as I would expect.
The 1st query returns pairs of ID values from the database.
sample pairs are: [1,2],[3,6],[10,15]

My 2nd query by iteratively inserting the trip pairs, retrieves the list of data as expected.

The 9979 and 240 values are constants for the purpose of the query.

Any suggestion on how to nest the 1st query within the 2nd query so I get all the results at once, grouped by the HID and SID as retrieved from query 1? (6000 discrete iterations isn’t a very tidy solution)

```
SELECT     TH1.THR_ID AS HID, SHEAD.THR_ID AS SID
        FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS SHEAD INNER JOIN
        RTDEV.TRIP_LINKS TLINK ON SHEAD.TME_ID = TLINK.TME_ID AND SHEAD.THR_ID =
        TLINK.PRIOR_SBSQUNT_THR_ID INNER JOIN
        RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS TH1 ON TLINK.TME_ID = TH1.TME_ID AND TLINK.THR_ID = TH1.THR_ID
        WHERE     (SHEAD.TME_ID = 9979) AND (TLINK.TME_ID = 9979) AND (TH1.TME_ID = 9979)         AND
        (TLINK.LINK_TYPE = 'S')
        ORDER BY SHEAD.TRIP_NAME

SELECT     ‘1’ AS HID, ‘2’ AS SID, RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TRIP_NAME,
     RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.DOP_REF,RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.DEPARTURE_TIME,RTDEV.TNODED.STRLONGNAME
        FROM         RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES INNER JOIN
        RTDEV.TNODED ON RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.MASTER_NODE = RTDEV.TNODED.NID INNER JOIN
        RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS ON RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TME_ID AND 
        RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.THR_ID = RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID
        WHERE (RTDEV.TNODED.NPROJECTGEOGRAPHYID = 240) AND (RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.TME_ID =
        9979) AND (RTDEV.TNODED.STRLONGNAME IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.ARRIVAL_TIME <> RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.DEPARTURE_TIME) AND
        (RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.TME_ID = 9979) AND 
        (RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID IN (1, 2))
        ORDER BY RTDEV.TRIP_BODIES.DEPARTURE_TIME
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*iteratively inserting the trip pairs*"?

Comment: I could generate 2nd query 6000 times replacing "(RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID IN (1, 2))" with "(RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID IN (3, 6))", then "(RTDEV.TRIP_HEADERS.THR_ID IN (10, 15))" etc, but this would be slow and tedious (as would 6000 UNIONS :))